# Ui Testing failure - No matches found for "CREATE PIN" Navigationbar

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing

```
var pcheck = XCUIApplication().navigationBars["CREATE PIN"].staticTexts["CREATE PIN"].label

  if pCheck == "CREATE PIN" {
    app.childrenMatchingType(.Window).elementBoundByIndex(0).childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).elementBoundByIndex(1).childrenMatchingType(.SecureTextField).element.typeText("1111")

    app.childrenMatchingType(.Window).elementBoundByIndex(0).childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).element.childrenMatchingType(.Other).elementBoundByIndex(1).childrenMatchingType(.SecureTextField).element.typeText("1111")
    } else {
        print("No Pin needed")
    }
```

The point of this snippet is to check to see if a certain window is being displayed. If the window is there then I need to create a pin code. If not... just carry on. This works when the window is present. However when the window is absent I get this error:

Ui Testing failure - No matches found for "CREATE PIN" Navigationbar

I have tried re-writting this to this

if XCUIApplication().navigationBars["CREATE PIN"].staticTexts["CREATE PIN"].label == "CREATE PIN" {fooBar}

And got the same result. All I want to do is check to see if a window is there if it is take an action... if its not take another.

Swift UI Testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to get staticText element from nonexisting parent.

```
let someElement = XCUIApplication().navigationBars["CREATE PIN"]
if (someElement.exists){  //also it may be someElement.hittable  
//do something 
}
```

So, you should check existing of the parent(navBar).
PS. Also it will be helpful to you to read about expectations and accessibilityIdentifiers.